# How to save transformed xml data to sql using GeomFromGML

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-2008

I have successfully converted a KML file to a GML file using XSLT and now I need to save the GML data to a geometry column in my SQL database. Not sure what to put after this code:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();
var fileName = Path.GetFileName(Polygon.FileName);
var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
Polygon.SaveAs(path);
doc.Load(path);
var result = new XmlActionResult();
result.Document = doc;
result.TransformSource = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/XSL/kml2gml.xsl");
return result;
```

Please help if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the xml, you write it to the db like any other insert.  SQL Server has an xml data type.  Use that to store your xml in a single column, that is best.  But if you need to break down the hierarchy and store it in different tables, that's pretty straightforward too.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        var fileName = @"C:\test.xml";
        doc.Load(fileName);
        var connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=MyServer; 
             Initial Catalog=MyDatabase; Integrated Security=SSPI");
        connection.Open();
        var command = new SqlCommand(
             "INSERT INTO dbo.Shapes (shape, desc) VALUES (@a, @b)", connection);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@a", SqlDbType.Xml);
        command.Parameters["@a"].Value = doc.OuterXml;
        command.Parameters.Add("@b", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters["@b"].Value = doc.InnerXml;
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: I need to break it down and store it in a geometry column. Saving it as xml won't work. I need to use GeomFromGML() but not sure how. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you want to store it in a single column, then what I have posted will work, as long as the column has the XML data type in sql server. GML IS XML.  So why won't it work?  Please provide more info.  I did a little research, and GeomFromGML() is a T-SQL function that returns an instance, you need to pass it your XML/GML and a spatial reference ID (integer type) to use it properly, but you cannot use it unless it is first stored in a column.  GemoFromGML is not an INSERT method.  Your original question was how to store it in a column, this is something else.  Lay out the complete requirement.

Comment: Check these links out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933842.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848797.  I should warn you well though, even seasoned DBAs freak out sometimes when you tell them you want CLR data types.  Good luck.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. Your definitely getting me closer to an answer. The column I need to save it to is Geometry data type.